# What is the resistance of this equivalent-circuit?

Tags: adc, input-impedance, equivalent-circuit

In order to cofigure an ADC, I need to know the input resistance to the ADC Pin of a uC, designated as `R_source` in the following equivalent circuit:

[image: R_source equivalent circuit]

From `R_source` the acquisition time `TACQ` can be read from the following table:

[image]

`TACQ` is what I need to find out.
Now, my schematic looks like this:

[image]

The ADC is the grey box at the top right.
My question is now, how can I calculate `R_source` from `R3` and `R4`?
When the switch closes, the cap looks like a short circuit to the DC. But as the charge increases, more current flows through `R4`, until the cap is fully charged.

Comment: You have two 100k impedances in parallel. Can you calculate it now?

Comment: Is V_bat a power supply ? If yes, what's its value ?

Comment: @Bouboubi Yes, V_bat is a power supply, and it corresponds to the voltage source in the equivalent circuit. It is maximum 4.3 V.

Comment: What is your input to the ADC supposed to be is it tp8 or Vbat?

Comment: @Bouboubi You are correct, and what is the impedance of two resistors, one pulling up to some voltage and one pulling down to some voltage?

Comment: @yasmeister It's `V_Bat`. `TP8` is a test point on the PCB. Sorry I didn't state that clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Thevenin equivalent of this arrangement of V_BAT, GND, R3 and R4 is shown on the right:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbuIwN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The effective source resistance is therefore \$R_{SOURCE}=50k\Omega \$, which puts acquisition time at a little over 5μs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I still don't get how I get from the voltage at the ADC input (V_Bat/2) to the conclusion that R_source is 50kOhms. Could you explain that further?

Comment: So, after reading on Wikipedia on how to calculate `R_th` of the Thevenin Equivalent, I now know that voltage sources can be considered as short circuits. This makes it super easy as `R3` and `R4` are now parallel resistances. Can you explain why the voltage source can be considered a short circuit?

Comment: @ilja I don't like calling it a short circuit, I prefer the term "has 0Ω internal resistance" instead. That means it doesn't matter how much current you draw from it, the voltage across it remains fixed. That is, effective resistance, which by Ohm's law is change in voltage across the thing divided by the change in current through it, is zero. You can interpret that as a "short circuit", but it's not telling the whole story. Recap: an ideal voltage source has no internal resistance, and the voltage across it will not change regardless of the amount or direction of current through it.

Comment: @ilja BTW thank you for reading up on Thevenin equivalent, it tells me you're serious about learning, and makes me feel my writing here is justified.

Comment: I used the term they used in the Wikipedia article. But with your explanation it is much clearer. Thank you for following up.